# not able to download files from azure blob

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

Hi using `fileUris` in Azure extension of template, not able to download file in VM while launching VM from template.

It throws following error:

> VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'customScript'. Error message: "Enable failed: processing file downloads failed: failed to download file[1]: failed to download file: unexpected status code: got=404 expected=200".

Answer (score 1):

To get more insight about the issue, you check the following log files on your VM:

```
  - /var/log/azure/custom-script/handler.log
  - /var/log/waagent.log
enter code here
```

Your files are downloaded to a path like: /var/lib/waagent/custom-script/download/0/ and the command output is saved to stdout and stderr files in this directory. Please read these files to find out output from your script.

You can find the logs for the extension at /var/log/azure/custom-script/handler.log.

Please open an issue on this GitHub repository if you encounter problems that you could not debug with these log files.

Source: **https://github.com/Azure/custom-script-extension-linux**

Answer (score 0):

Plese check weather your repository is private or public in github or any reposi.
Once you chenge it to public it let you download the repository

Answer (score 0):

For storage private networking I needed to add the subnet of the VM to the firewall and enable the "Microsoft.Storage" services endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

The message means that the waagent service was not able to download a file using the URL provided in the config file. There could be many reasons for that. I suggest that you need to test that URL manually from the VM to see if the URL can be downloaded at all.

Comment: able to download a file by using same url